# Excel (Microsoft 365): INNER JOIN of Two Tables within Same Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I am using Excel (Microsoft 365) and have two identically-structured tables, each in its own worksheet. These two worksheets are in the same workbook. The first worksheet and the table it holds are both named `Table_A`. The second worksheet and the table it holds are both named `Table_B`. Both tables have fields `Field_A`, `Field_B`, `Field_C`. Within each table, `Field_A` has a unique value for each row (i.e., can be thought of as a primary key in database parlance).

I have a third worksheet named `Join`. This worksheet is in the same workbook as the first two worksheets described above. Within this worksheet, I would like to create a table named `Join` that is populated with the data I'd get with the following T-SQL statement if I were using SQL Server rather than Excel:

```
SELECT Table_A.Field_A, Table_A.Field_B, Table_B.Field_B, Table_A.Field_C, Table_B.Field_C
FROM Table_A INNER JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.Field_A = Table_B.Field_A;
```

How may I do this within my Excel workbook? Please note that since this is all self-contained within a single workbook, I would like to avoid any filename references as data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Query is the tool you are looking for here.

Let's say this is our data. For clarity I've named the columns in Table2 D and E rather than repeating B and C.

**Table1**

[image: dummy data in Table1]

**Table2**:

[image: dummy data in Table2]

First, right-click **Table1** and select **Get Data from Table/Range**.

[image: Get Data from Table/Range]

The Power Query Editor window will open and it will show you your new data source called **Table1**.

[image: Power Query Editor showing Table1]

In the top left, click the **down arrow button under Close & Load**, then choose the **Close & Load To...** option. In the next box, select **Only Create Connection** then click **OK**.

[image: Close & Load To...]

[image: Only Create Connection]

The editor will close and the Queries & Connections panel should appear on the right. Now we'll add Table2, by right-clicking and selecting **Get Data from Table/Range**.

The Power Query Editor will open again. On the left hand side there is a panel called Queries. Right click in the space below Table2, and select **New Query > Combine > Merge Queries as New**.

[image: Merge Queries data source]

You can now configure the join as you would like - in this case, select **Table1**, then **Table2**, click to select column **Field1A** then column **Field2A** and finally from the drop down, select join kind **Inner (only matching rows)**. Click **OK**.

[image: Power Query Merge]

You'll see a new data source appear in Power Query called **Merge1**. On the right you'll see Table2 shown as a column but the columns won't be expanded - you need to click the expand button to do so. You can opt not to show the join field again if you don't want to.

[image: Expand table columns]

[image: Deselect the join field]

Now in the top left, click the **Close & Load** button and the join table will appear as a new sheet in your workbook. Changes made in Table1 and Table2 will only cascade through when you click to refresh your new **Table_Merge1**.

[image: Final output]

Comment: Fantastic, detailed explanation! Greatly appreciated!

As a follow-up... Is it possible to get Excel to prefix "Table1" to the column names taken from Table1, just as it prefixes "Table2" to the column names taken from Table2?

If not, or if not easily, no worries... What you've already provided is more than sufficient. Again, greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Dave you can't get "Table1." automatically prefixed to the column names during the merge, but you can manually double-click the column headers in the Power Query Editor to add them yourself: https://imgur.com/a/VWXAQvl